# Haskell: Multiset (Bag) Representation

Tags: function, haskell, functional-programming, multiset, bag

Currently, I am working on trying to take a list of integers (Int), and put them into a multiset representation. For a little background, the representation would look like this:

```
*user passes in a list:* [1,2,3,4]
*multiset representation:* [(1,1),(2,1),(3,1),(4,1)]
```

I have written two functions: *add* and *del*. *add* takes an integer and a bag, and inserts the integer into the bag. It checks for duplicates - if there are, it simply increments the counter (second element of coordinate in bag) by 1. It then returns that bag.

So, my algorithm should be: take the list, say [1,2,3,4]; go through each element in the list - and for each of these elements, call *add* with the parameters being the current element and the bag. For the next element, do the same - pass the element, with the bag that was returned from the previous *add* call.

Here's what I'm shaky on: how would I actually code this? I've put my (not so good) attempt down below. I've figured out the algorithm completely, but am unsure of how to execute this. Any tips in the right direction would be great.

```
multi :: Eq a => [a] -> Bag a
multi [] = []
multi (x:xs) = ins x []
```

Comment: This is a typical case of a `fold`.

Comment: If you can rely on `Ord`, sorting them first is going to make for a cleaner implementation and also be more efficient than anything that can be done with `Eq` alone.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I'll take a look at fold really quick.

Comment: @Ry Unfortunately, this is the function declaration that I have to use.

Comment: Hint: you don't want to insert `x` into an empty bag, you want to insert it into the bag that already has the contents of `xs` inside -- that is, the bag constructed by `multi xs`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, you've figured out the algorithm; you can translate it almost directly into Haskell:

```
-- So, my algorithm should be: take the list, say [1,2,3,4];
multi :: Eq a => [a] -> Bag a
-- go through each element in the list
multi [] = []
multi (x:xs) =
  -- and for each of these elements, call add with the parameters being the current element
  -- and the bag.
  let returnedBag = add x theBag
  -- For the next element, do the same - pass the element, with the bag that was returned 
  -- from the previous add call.
  in doTheSame xs returnedBag
```

Of course, this doesn't quite work, because two definitions are missing: what is `doTheSame`, and what is `theBag`? Well, we'd want `doTheSame` to mean everything in the body of `multi` right now, but notice that we want to pass two arguments to `doTheSame` instead of the one that `multi` takes. So let's try making `doTheSame` its own function:

```
-- So, my algorithm should be: take the list, say [1,2,3,4];
multi :: Eq a => [a] -> Bag a
-- go through each element in the list
multi elts = doTheSame elts ???
  where
  doTheSame [] theBag = ???
  doTheSame (x:xs) theBag =
    -- and for each of these elements, call add with the parameters being the current element
    -- and the bag.
    let returnedBag = add x theBag
    -- For the next element, do the same - pass the element, with the bag that was returned 
    -- from the previous add call.
    in doTheSame xs returnedBag
```

This solves what `theBag` is—it's just whatever's passed to `doTheSame`. But now we have some `???` placeholders in there which need to be filled with something. What should `multi` do when it's done processing elements? Return the bag it has been building, no doubt:

```
-- So, my algorithm should be: take the list, say [1,2,3,4];
multi :: Eq a => [a] -> Bag a
-- go through each element in the list
multi elts = doTheSame elts ???
  where
  doTheSame [] theBag = theBag
  doTheSame (x:xs) theBag =
    -- and for each of these elements, call add with the parameters being the current element
    -- and the bag.
    let returnedBag = add x theBag
    -- For the next element, do the same - pass the element, with the bag that was returned 
    -- from the previous add call.
    in doTheSame xs returnedBag
```

And what about the `???` first given to `doTheSame`? That must be the bag that you start with—presumably, an empty bag. (You'll need to define what that is for yourself.)

```
-- So, my algorithm should be: take the list, say [1,2,3,4];
multi :: Eq a => [a] -> Bag a
-- go through each element in the list
multi elts = doTheSame elts emptyBag
  where
  doTheSame [] theBag = theBag
  doTheSame (x:xs) theBag =
    -- and for each of these elements, call add with the parameters being the current element
    -- and the bag.
    let returnedBag = add x theBag
    -- For the next element, do the same - pass the element, with the bag that was returned 
    -- from the previous add call.
    in doTheSame xs returnedBag
```

This code works, assuming you have a definition of `add` and `emptyBag`! But you might want to tidy it up a little. A more experienced Haskell programmer would probably use some shorter names, and bring `returnedBag` inline:

```
-- So, my algorithm should be: take the list, say [1,2,3,4]; go through each element in the
-- list - and for each of these elements, call add with the parameters being the current
-- element and the bag. For the next element, do the same - pass the element, with the bag
-- that was returned from the previous add call.
multi :: Eq a => [a] -> Bag a
multi elts = go elts emptyBag
  where go [] bag = bag
        go (x:xs) bag = go xs (add x bag)
```

This code is exactly the same as the previous—the only reason to prefer one over the other is whether you find one easier to read. (Never underestimate the importance of being able to read your own code, and never *overestimate* your ability to do so after some time has passed and it's no longer fresh in your mind!)

---

Extra credit:

This kind of recursion is very common in functional languages in general, and is typically called a *fold*. A fold starts with some data (in this case, an empty bag), walks over a list or list-like structure, and for each element in that structure, uses a function (in this case, add) to combine the data with the element to make new data, which is used on the next element, and so on, returning the final value of the data (in this case, a bag with all your elements). Since this is a common pattern, in Haskell, there is a function called `foldl` (for *left fold*, since you're processing your list elements starting from the left) that takes just a combining function, an initial value, and a list, and does all the rest of the work for you:

```
multi :: Eq a => [a] -> Bag a
multi elts = foldl (\bag x -> add x bag) emptyBag elts
```

While you're still learning about recursion and the basics of Haskell, I wouldn't try too hard to write code in the style of that last version of `multi`. But once you've done the `where go` trick a few times and have gotten sick of writing all that out every time, go look up `foldl` and `foldr` and take the next step!